# Selecting AngularJS vs jQuery/Ajax for Share Point 2013 web parts

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sharepoint-2013

I am relatively new in C# and SharePoint environment.(I have some Java back ground though.)
I worked on a couple of projects that basically converts Access to SharePoint 2013 web parts. One of the projects is getting bigger and I started to add jQuery feature something like jQuery dataTable and clients like it.(of course it is a lot faster than server side language.)
Now I am thinking to extend/convert to other functionalities of the application and I am wondering I should consider something like AngularJS.(I have studied AngularJS with J2EE a while ago.)

The current SharePoint web parts just acts like existing Access program and has full CRUD operations, populating applicant’s record on a form, some associated forms in jQuery tabs with its own create and update buttons and upload file functionality etc… with SQL server backend.

I can’t use ASP.NET since I have to do everything inside of SharePoint 2013 environment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely suggest you go with AngularJs especially if you already have experience on it. You just need to write angular code and upload it in one of your designated Sharepoint libraries. Then add the content editor web part on the Sharepoint page and point the CE Web part to the HTML of the angular app . That's all.. of course ..it will take you some hit and try to figure it out exactly how to do it but once done you can use the same pattern to write full fledged SharePoint applications using AngularJS. To perform crud operations you can use Sharepoint REST APIs or SharePoint JSOM. Hope this helps...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Visual Studio so the deploy process will be a bit different. I didn't know about Sharepoint REST APIs or SharePoint JSOM. I will look into it. Thanks!